# Creating a Simple Line Graph in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, graph, linegraph

I would like to create a simple Line Graph like the following,

[image]

I googled to find out some sample and I got CorePlot which looks too heavy. Can anyone suggest me how to create a kind of line graph like below or tutorial is also most welcome. Please

Comment: one of the possibilities is [here](http://blogs.remobjects.com/blogs/mh/2010/01/26/p973)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you can use this https://github.com/pyanfield/WSChart

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, why calling that graph simple? You can make it by drawing vertical lines along the X coordinate. You have (probably) an array with the top points (that show the weight progress), so you draw a line from a top point till the base line in a loop that will parse all your top points. Here is the code to draw a line, call it for each top point:

```
-(void)drawLineFromX:(CGPoint)topPoint{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(instanceToYourImageView.image.size);
    [instanceToYourImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, instanceToYourImageView.image.size.width, instanceToYourImageView.image.size.height)]; 
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), topPoint.x, topPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), topPoint.x, topPoint.y + a_value_to_reach_the_base_line);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    [instanceToYourImageView setImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Here the `CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);` is black, but you can easily change it to the desired one.

Cheers!